# Generating icons for iPhone UITabBar

Tags: iphone, png, uitabbarcontroller, transparency, icons

I’ve been busy working on the graphics for my iPhone application.  I started working on generating icons for my UITabBar and ran into lots of problems.  How do you create these icons?

I created this solution:

http://www.nailrails.com/?p=46

Are there any shortcomings to this approach?  It seemed to work for the few icons I created...

Comment: why not post your solution here rather than a link to your blog?

Comment: by the way I get this: `-bash: convert: command not found`

Answer (score 11):

Apple's guidelines can be found at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW1

Comment: Thank you, this should be the top answer.

Answer (score 7):

The docs are pretty straightforward-- alpha is all that matters when the image gets loaded by the toolbar, meaning that anything that's not at least semitransparent will render in the same opaque shade.  As for how I do that, I mainly use Adobe tools.  Fireworks is my preferred tool but Photoshop's also more than up to it.  Another one I've had good results with is Acorn, which is frankly a lot cheaper while being more than sophisticated enough for this kind of work.  I'm not really a graphic designer but a certain familiarity with this kind of stuff goes with the job.

Answer (score 6):

I have an article up on my site that shows how to use OmniGraffle with a template I use to create great iPhone toolbar icons in minutes:

http://steveweller.com/articles/toolbar-icons/

The template sets up a grid to work to that corresponds to one square for each pixel. You draw your icon in white on top of the black template background and then export as a PDF exactly the right area to match the icon size you need (typically 21 pixels high). Then you reimport the PDF, resize it to the final icon size (21 pixels again), and export as PNG. The template does nothing magical; it just provides an already set up working area and helps you get the final PNG right every time to the scale is correct.

You could use the same technique in Acorn or any other app that supports PDF export and layers.

Comment: When I came to this question, this is exactly the sort of step-by-step walkthrough for which I was looking.  Thanks!

Comment: P.S.  I thought there used to be an Apple-doc that gave that sort of step-by-step with image examples for TabBar icons, but I can't seem to find it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

(I use Gimp. Assume your icon layer already has alpha channel.)

1. Right click the layer, then add layer mask.
2. Done with option "transfer alpha channel of layer" chosen.
3. Select the whole layer (but not layer mask), and clear it with pure white.
4. Resize image to Apple-suggested size, and export it as png file.

You may also paint directly on the layer mask.